# sbt-1.1.1 sbtVersion showing 1.1.0

Tags: sbt

I invoke:

```
brew install sbt
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.1.1: 491 files, 48.3MB, built in 7 seconds
```

I invoke:

```
sbt sbtVersion
```

I get:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/name/project
[info] Set current project to name (in build file:/Users/name/)
[info] 1.1.0
```

I'm expecting to see

```
[info] 1.1.1
```

Why don't the version values match?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, because you have a file `project/build.properties` with line

```
sbt.version=1.1.0
```

So one thing is the version of the *launcher* that you installed with Homebrew and another is the version of the sbt you launch in particular project. If you don't set it explicitly in `project/build.properties`, sbt will try to run its own version (launcher's, i.e. 1.1.1 in your case).

Another possible reason is that Homebrew could install the formula, but not link the binaries (assuming you upgraded from sbt 1.1.0). You can run several commands to verify which versions you have

```
$ brew info sbt
...

$ brew list --versions sbt
sbt 0.13.16 0.13.11 1.0.0 1.0.1 1.1.0 0.13.12 0.13.15 1.1.1 0.13.13 1.0.4 1.0.3 1.0.2

$ brew list sbt
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.1.1/bin/sbt
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.1.1/libexec/bin/ (5 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.1.1/libexec/lib/ (483 files)
```

You can see here that I have many old versions installed, but the one linked is 1.1.1. In case I need to switch to an older launcher, I can run `brew switch sbt 1.0.4`, for example.

Comment: Many thanks @laughedelic you're correct the version value was coming from project/build.properties. Seems that project/build.properties is auto created from where ever sbt sbtVersion is run. It seems that I have run sbt sbtVersion previously before the upgrade and ran again from the same location after the upgrade hence the old version value was being picked from a previously created project/build.properties. Thank you.

Comment: @jakstack I think this behaviour was introduced in sbt 1.x, and it creates the file whenever you run sbt, not only `sbt sbtVersion`. The point is that you should always have this file (created manually or automatically), because your build definition depends on the sbt version.