# I downloaded sbt 1.1.4 but why was sbt 0.13 installed?

Tags: sbt

I downloaded sbt 1.1.4 msi for Windows from [the scala download page](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).

I ran the msi. After typing sbt about, sbt downloaded all the required files.
When i ran sbt about, it said the version is 0.13

Answer (score 3):

As I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089456/736957) to a similar question (adapted):

> Most likely, because you have a file `project/build.properties` with *the 0.13 version*.
>
> So one thing is the version of the *launcher* that you installed and another is the version of the sbt you launch in particular project. If you don't set it explicitly in `project/build.properties`, sbt will try to run its own version (launcher's, i.e. 1.1.4 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

**short answer**

might be best to go to `Users/You/project/`, delete everything and put a new `build.properties` file there with your desired sbt version before trying to install.

**more detail, in case it helps someone**

I had a similar problem.  I'd updated sbt to 1.2 but when I uninstalled and tried reinstalling with the 0.13.7 installer, it would only install sbt 1.2 again.  All of my projects had `sbt.version=0.13.7`, but I didn't realize (though it's obvious why) that there was a `C:/Users/Me/project` folder with version set to 1.2.

I deleted everything from that folder, put a new `build.properties` with the desired version, and then the 0.13.7 installer worked as expected.